# Prestashop modules/path is not found

Tags: php, ajax, apache, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

guys today i install modules for version 1.7.X on my prestashop store, my prestashop version is correct 1.7.X but if i try to open modules in browser developer console i found this error : `http://motokayak.eu/modules/econt/ajax.php?ajax_function=get_cities_by_name&q=dsad&limit=10&timestamp=1526125310888 404 (Not Found)` My file is in folder but prestashop not founded and if i try to open this link http://motokayak.eu/modules/econt/ajax.php in my browser site return 404 not found why ?

[Picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oxC6a.png)
[image]

[Picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mV0Kv.png)
[image]

[Picture 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMUbq.png)
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with a new module. It was a problem with wrong permissions on folder and files.

You can verify this with another standard module to see if you can access without problem.

Check the permissions and try again. Folders 755 and Files 644.

I hope this can help you.